# vSphere Virtual Machine Windows Explorer runs slow

Tags: vmware-vsphere, windows-explorer

I've a number of Server 2008 and 2003 virtual machines running on vSphere 4.

When using Windows Explorer on any of them, it runs very slow, e.g. 60 seconds + to change a folder. These folders are also shared, and browsing them from the clients over the network is perfectly fine.

It's doesn't matter if I use vSphere Client to access the VM's, or MSTSC, Windows Explorer runs very slow.

Suggestions?

Comment: Specific folders, or any folders? What's the content of these folders, and how many items per folder? How deep is the folder structure?

Comment: Any folder, any drive, local or network.  Think, I've found it, as per below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be Kaspersky.  I'd tried disabling it, but apparently not enough.  After some more Google-fu, removing it entirely fixed it, and then reinstalling it seems to remain okay.